# How to remove some compile options in a subdirectory for a bazel project?

Tags: bazel

I am using tensorflow and adding a subdirectory in it. Found the root .bazelrc suppressed C++ all warnings:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/.bazelrc#L296

I would like to have warnings in my newly-created folder, but after googling for a while, didn't get one. Anyone can give me a hand? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`cc_library` has a `copt` attribute for compiler flags, which get added to the compiler command line after the options in a .bazelrc. You could try adding the warning flags there.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.copts